# Wo sollte das Pronomen stehen?

Tags: colloquial

Was ist richtig?

> Falls Herr Leopold umkommt, werden mir alle seine Vermögenswerte vermacht.

> Falls Herr Leopold umkommt, werden alle seine Vermögenswerte mir vermacht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beides ist richtig, aber die erste Variante ist die neutralere. Die zweite Variante kann gewählt werden, um "mir" zu betonen.